# How to fetch data from database in Laravel 8 Jetstream register page?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

So I have a model named Role. I want to show a dropdown where the roles are visible from the Role model. How can I get all the data from the roles model in my registration page? I want to show them on a dropdown select menu. My question is how to get data from the Role Model in my register.blade.php file?

Below is my CreateNewUser.php code-

```
public function create(array $input)
    {
        dd($input);
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'business_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'category_id' => ['required'],
            'role_id' => ['required'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/','max:11','unique:users'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],

            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();
        
        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'business_name' => $input['business_name'],
            'category_id' => $input['category_id'],
            'role_id' => $input['role_id'],
            'phone' => $input['phone'],
            'address' => $input['address'],

            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password'])
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: How do you usually get model data? `Role::all()` doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Jetstream I think use Fortify package for auth backend logic. So, if this is the case you must have in App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::registerView(function () {
        return view('auth.register');
    });
}
```

then in this you can pass the data to the register view like:

```
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::registerView(function () {
        $roles = Role::all();
        return view('auth.register',compact('roles'));
    });
}
```

add in the register view the select element

```
//.....
<select name="role_id">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 @foreach($roles as $item)
   <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option> 
 @endforeach
</select>
//.....
```